# Delete values in table depending on two criteras in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

[My two tables and the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVH9z.png)

I want to delete values in table 1 on two different criterias;

End date is exceeded **or** if "Campaign ID" in table 1 can't be found in table 2.

I have marked the values I wish to delete in red.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
update table1
    left join table2 on table1.campaignid=table2.campaignid
set campaignid=''
where table2.campaignid is null or table2.enddate < now()
```

I found this post which may help as well:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/